# Why isnt the World Championship formatted like that?

Tags: fide, world-championship

Just have the Men's section, Women's section and Junior's section and the 3 winners play each other in a quadruple robin round format (each player plays 8 games) and the winner becomes the next World Champion.Why isn't the World Championship formatted like that?

Answer (score 4):

> Why isn't the World Championship formatted like that?

Because it makes no sense.

First, your assumptions are wrong. There is no "Men's" section. There is an open section which, as implied, is open to everyone. Both women and juniors are free to enter. The Candidates places are open for all players. Whoever qualifies, man, woman, junior, is entitled to play in the Candidates. Whoever wins that, man, woman or junior, then gets to play the reigning world champion for the title. The open world champion is THE world champion.

Comment: Or at least make the Womens and Juniors World Champion qualify for the Candidates.

Comment: And take away a spot  from somebody who has been through the *open* qualifying procedure? What if that person was a women or a junior? *Anybody* can enter the open section. *That* is the way to qualify.

Comment: I mean shouldnt we reward the fact that someone is a champion?

Answer (score 2):

- The real action would currently all be in the Men's section. A woman or person under 20 has never been world champion.
- A 3 way format would be, perhaps, unfair. If player A lost all their games to player B but put up a fight against player C, then B could win the championship despite a losing record against C.
- This format does not allow the current champion to defend their World Champion title, as is usually done.
- It's unnecessary. Under current practice anyone meeting the criteria can contend for the title; there's not a "Men's section" which excludes women or juniors.

Comment: Or at least make the Womens and Juniors World Champion qualify for the Candidates.

Comment: @Cerise Hmm. They don't get an automatic berth to the Candidates but they *do* both get an automatic berth in the World Cup, and the top three in the World Cup tournament qualify for the candidates. The Women's World Champion also gets an automatic berth in the FIDE Grand Swiss, and the top two from that tournament get berths in the Candidates. So there is, at least, a clear path.

Comment: Ah okay this sounds fair.